# Express Routing Issue using moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, momentjs

I'm new to express.js and backend routing. Below is the exact error and source code I have for my server so far. Any direction as to what the issue is would be appreciated. I've already tried using `res.end()` with plain text inside of it, and it is still returning the same error.

Thanks everyone.

```
_http_outgoing.js:489

throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
   at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at Array.write (/app/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:254:9)
    at listener (/app/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (/app/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
    at callback (/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
    at IncomingMessage.onevent (/app/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:93:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
```

`

on this code:

`

```
//server.js

// Set static routes and set view engine as pug
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


// Pug entry point to API

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Timestamp Microservice API'})
});

app.get('/:time',function (req,res, moment) {
  var time = req.params.time;
  return moment(time, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid();
});



// listen for requests :)

var listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

```

Comment: Why have you got moment as a parameter to your get handler?..   Just place moment in your usually require's at the top of your unit.  `res.end()` is also the correct way.  the get request is async so the return is most likely ignored in express.  The 3rd parameter is the `next` callback, this is what you call if your don't handle the request.

Comment: moment is a handler there, because express returns a moment is undefined  error if I try to use moment's methods within the callback.

Comment: If you define   `var moment = require('moment')` at the top of your javascript code, it can't be undefined.  Like I said the 3rd parameter is the `next` handler, this is called if you don't handle the request.  Also your route  `/:time` it would catch everything from the root url,..  Maybe  `/time/:time` might be better..  You would then call from url as   `/time/09-01-2017`

Comment: So within the app.get, can I pass the parameter outside of the function to work with it, and then pass it back into the response?

Comment: I assume you want to return true / false, as that's what isValid in momentjs is going to do.. so just do ->  `res.end(moment(req.params.time, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid());`

Comment: That works like a dream. Thanks. Can you post an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.get('/:time',function (req,res, moment) {
  var time = req.params.time;
  return moment(time, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid();
});
```

In the above code you have basically exposed the next handler and called it moment.

To access momentjs, just place `var moment = require('moment');` at the top of your unit, not need to pass into any parameters.

Next, if all your wanting then to do is valididate dates using momentjs, just res.end it's results.

eg.

```
app.get('/:time',function (req,res) {
  var time = req.params.time;
  res.end( moment(time, 'MM-DD-YYYY').isValid() );
});
```

Also in the above route we have  `/:time`  this would match urls like  `/anything`  you could do this, but normally you would apply a route for something like this..  eg..   `app.get('/time/:time',`  this would then match url's like  `/time/09-01-2017` stopping collisions from say `index.html favicon.ico` etc.